# Conflicts with custom alignment guides in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui, alignment

In my project I have to use custom alignment guides with nested views. It is quite complex, but I'll try to simplify my case in the following way:

There are 3 possible views: a circle, an upContainer and a downContainer. The two containers are just arrays of other circles/containers. The downContainer aligns only first array to the current line (where there are, for example, the other circles), regardless of what is inside the second array; the upContainer does the opposite. Here's an image to visualize them:[image]

I want to be able to build complex views dynamically using this three elements. Thus I create a data model (which is a simple enum) with nested associated types:

```
enum Data: Hashable {
    case circle
    case upContainer([Data], [Data])
    case downContainer([Data], [Data])
}
```

In order to manually align the three elements I create a custom SwiftUI alignment in this way:

```
extension VerticalAlignment {
    struct MyAlignment: AlignmentID {
        static func defaultValue(in context: ViewDimensions) -> CGFloat {
            context[VerticalAlignment.center]
        }
    }

    static let myAlignment = VerticalAlignment(MyAlignment.self)
}
```

I want the circles in a specific container to have the same color, so I create an extension to quickly generate a random color:

```
extension Color {
    static var random: Color {
        return Color(
            red: .random(in: 0...1),
            green: .random(in: 0...1),
            blue: .random(in: 0...1)
        )
    }
}
```

Now I am able to create the views corresponding to the three elements:

```
struct CirclesView: View {

var circles: [Data]

var color: Color = Color.random

var body: some View {
    HStack(alignment: .myAlignment) {
        ForEach(circles, id: \.self) { value in
            switch value {
            case .circle:
                Circle()
                    .frame(width: 20, height: 20)
                    .foregroundColor(color)
            case .upContainer(let firstData, let secondData):
                UpContainerView(container: (firstData, secondData))
            case .downContainer(let firstData, let secondData):
                DownContainerView(container: (firstData, secondData))
            }
        }
    }
}

}

struct UpContainerView: View {

var container: ([Data], [Data])

var color = Color.random

var body: some View {
    VStack(alignment: .leading) {
        CirclesView(circles: container.0, color: color)
        
        CirclesView(circles: container.1, color: color)
            .alignmentGuide(.myAlignment) { $0[VerticalAlignment.center] }
    }
}

}

struct DownContainerView: View {

var container: ([Data], [Data])

var color = Color.random

var body: some View {
    VStack(alignment: .leading) {
        CirclesView(circles: container.0, color: color)
            .alignmentGuide(.myAlignment) { $0[VerticalAlignment.center] }
        
        
        CirclesView(circles: container.1, color: color)
    }
}

}
```

At this point the problem should be solved. For example, if I wanted to render this image:[image]

I should be able to do it by writing:

```
struct ContentView : View {


var myData: [Data] = [.circle, .circle, .downContainer(
                        [.circle, .circle, .circle, .downContainer(
                            [.circle, .circle, .circle, .circle], [.circle]
                        )], [.circle, .circle, .upContainer(
                            [.circle, .circle], [.circle, .circle, .circle, .circle]
                        )]
)]

var body: some View {
    CirclesView(circles: myData)
}

}
```

However this is the result:

[image]

As you can see, the first container (the brown one) is not rendered as downContainer, in fact it is in centrally aligned to the first two circles green circles. This is because even if we set explicit alignment guides for only one of the two arrays, SwiftUI takes into account also the alignment guides of the subviews of the other array (even if we want to ignore them) and there is a conflict.

```
struct DownContainerView: View {

var container: ([Data], [Data])

var color = Color.random

var body: some View {
    VStack(alignment: .leading) {
        CirclesView(circles: container.0, color: color)
            .alignmentGuide(.myAlignment) { $0[VerticalAlignment.center] }
        
        //We set the explicit alignment guide only for the first array, I am looking for a way to ignore completely the alignment guides of the second one and to calculate the alignment based only on the first one.
        
        CirclesView(circles: container.1, color: color)
    }
}

}
```

To solve the conflict we should simply ignore the alignment guides of the other array.
The actual question becomes "How can we ignore those alignment guides, which are implicitly and automatically calculated by SwiftUI?"

Note: I now that a different solution could be to use PreferenceKeys, but I believe this problem should be solved using only alignment guides, since it is a mere alignment problem. I also thought that a solution could be to dynamically create a new custom alignment guide for every subcontainer, but I don't how to do it (if it is possible in Swift).

Comment: I had already read that article, but there the author doesn’t have to handle nested view, thus my problem doesn’t occur. As for what you say about alignment guides not being activated, they actually are: CircleViews is the parent view which defines an HStack with alignment of type “myAlignment”. Then upContainer and downContainer have two subviews (which I called arrays), and only one of them declares an explicit guide. Thanks for the attention, if you need any further clarification feel free to ask. I know this question is quite complex but I am really stuck.

Comment: On *I wanted to render this image* - by your logic it cannot be started with regular .circle, because two blues are at the top, so it should start with .upContainer. Am I wrong? I still hardly understand your goal & logic.

Comment: Thanks again for the interest, I really appreciate it. My goal is to understand how custom alignment guide interact with each other in nested views. In the image I wanted to represent, the two initial blue circles don't belong to a container, in fact they lie only on one row of circles. Instead the red, yellow and pink ones are represented on two rows, which means they are in a container. The red one must be a downContainer, since it aligns only the top circles to the blue ones (and so the yellow one), while pink is "up", because it aligns the bottom circles to the previous ones (the red).

Comment: Well, as you described I fill that you expect that alignment guides will fit to each other in the order of added elements, but it is not so. The container gives reference alignment guide. In your case it is HStack with .center to which all internal align by their introduced (implicit or explicit) alignment guides. So, there is one line introduced by your top HStack.center, so first 2 blues are centered vertically (always!!), then you have VStack of VStack, which will finally also be centred, what is actually observed (as far as as I see).

Comment: Exactly! The question is "I don't want it to be observed, how can I do it?". I want to ignore the alignment guides that I don't set explicitly. For one layer of nested views it just works because it seems that explicit guides have higher priority over implicit guides (just look at the blue and gray containers, they are aligned as I wanted), but if there is an explicit guide in a subview it counts as well, and I want to ignore it ! I hope I finally managed to explain myself, sorry if I have not been clear.

Answer (score 2):

First up some background info that might help:

1. EVERY view has EXACTLY ONE alignment which is an x and y value in the coordinate system of the view. Note there is no name (like `.top` or `.leading`) mentioned here, those are just ways to tell the view which x an y value to return as the alignment guide for this layout.
2. If you don't tell the view which alignment to use, it defaults to `.center`.
3. The *parent* view uses the child alignment guides by calculating where that coordinate is in its own coordinate system and places all the children so the alignments are all coincident. Some parents may ignore the child value and place the child where it wants (such as a `HStack` which ignores the x value of its children and places the children side by side.)

The OP asks if the problem can be solved with layout alone, or are preferences required?

The answers are: it can be done with layout alone depending on how sophisticated you need to be, but you may need preferences depending on how sophisticated you need to be.

Looking at the OPs example we see that a `CirclesView` is an alias for a `HStack` and both up and down containers are aliases for a `VStack` containing two `CirclesView`s.

Also the test case only has `CirclesView`s with `Circle`s and either an `UpContainerView` or a `DownContainerView` (never both up and down, which gives a false impression of how well the layout is working, it is not even as good as the OP thinks).

So unrolling the test data, using the `HStack`s and `VStack`s directly, using `Text` with fixed colours so we can tell what is what and putting it all into one view so we can play with alignment gives:

```
struct SOAlignment: View {
    var body: some View {
        HStack { //CirclesView (solid gray)
            Text("C")
                .foregroundColor(Color.blue)
                .overlay(Rectangle().strokeBorder(style: StrokeStyle(lineWidth: 1.0, dash: [5,5])))
            Text("C")
                .foregroundColor(Color.blue)
                .overlay(Rectangle().strokeBorder(style: StrokeStyle(lineWidth: 1.0, dash: [5,5])))
            VStack(alignment: .leading) { //DownContainerView (black dashes)
                HStack { //CirclesView (top gray dashes)
                    Text("C")
                        .foregroundColor(Color.red)
                    Text("C")
                        .foregroundColor(Color.red)
                    Text("C")
                        .foregroundColor(Color.red)
                    VStack(alignment: .leading) { //DownContainerView (yellow)
                        HStack {
                            Text("C")
                            Text("C")
                            Text("C")
                            Text("C")
                        }
                        HStack {
                            Text("C")
                        }
                    }
                    .foregroundColor(Color.yellow)
                }
                .foregroundColor(Color.red)
                .overlay(Rectangle()
                            .inset(by: 1.0)
                            .strokeBorder(style: StrokeStyle(lineWidth: 0.5, dash: [2.5,2.5]))
                            .foregroundColor(Color.gray))
                HStack { //CirclesView (bottom gray dashes)
                    Text("C")
                        .foregroundColor(Color.red)
                    Text("C")
                        .foregroundColor(Color.red)
                    VStack(alignment: .leading) { //UpContainerView (pink)
                        HStack {
                            Text("C")
                            Text("C")
                        }
                        HStack {
                            Text("C")
                            Text("C")
                            Text("C")
                            Text("C")
                        }
                    }
                    .foregroundColor(Color.lightPink)
                }
                .overlay(Rectangle()
                            .inset(by: 1.0)
                            .strokeBorder(style: StrokeStyle(lineWidth: 0.5, dash: [2.5,2.5]))
                            .foregroundColor(Color.gray))

            }
            .overlay(Rectangle().strokeBorder(style: StrokeStyle(lineWidth: 1.0, dash: [5,5])))
        }
        .border(Color.gray.opacity(0.5))
        .padding()
    }
}
```

I have added `.leading` horizontal alignment so the output is as close to the circle example as possible, but these play no role so can be ignored. We are only interested in the vertical alignment.

We get the following output.

[image: all default center alignment]

I have put borders around the top level views. The top `CirclesView` is solid gray, it contains a blue `Circle`, a blue `Circle` and a `DownContainerView` all with black dashes, and the `DownContainerView` contains two `CirclesView`s with gray dashes.

None of the views have an alignment, by which I mean *every* view has *exactly one* alignment which has the default `.center` value. It is worth pausing for a second here—we are trying to align circles and they all have alignment guides at their centres but the centres of the blue circles do not align with any of the centres of the other coloured circles! The centres of the two black dashed blue circles are of course aligned with the centre of the black dashed `DownContainerView`/`VStack`.

The fact that the circles have been substituted for text hints at a possible solution. This is precisely the same problem that Apple solved with `.firstTextBaseline` and `.lastTextBaseline`. We want our top three red circles to align with the top row of the yellow down container, and we want the bottom two red circles to align with the bottom row of the pink up container. We can achieve this by putting `.firstTextBaseline` on the top gray dashed `CirclesView` and `.lastTextBaseline` on the bottom gray dashed `CirclesView`. Now that those are aligned we can also put `.firstTextBaseline` on the solid gray `CirclesView`.

e.g.

```
HStack(alignment: .firstTextBaseline) { //CirclesView (solid gray)
```

And we get...

[image: using text baseline alignment]

Hooray problem solved! Not quite: we put the alignment property on the *parent* `CirclesView`/`HStack` not the child `Up/DownContainer`/`VStack`. The point is illustrated by changing the solid gray view alignment to `.lastTextBaseline`

```
HStack(alignment: .lastTextBaseline) { //CirclesView (solid gray)
```

The black dashed `DownContainerView` has been turned into a black dashed `UpContainerView` without any changes to itself!

[image: parent changes meaning of child]

This is what I hinted at previously about having only one type of container in a `CirclesView` in the test example data. We need to ensure that `CirclesView`s with both up and down containers work but with this solution the property on the `CirclesView` (first or last text baseline) turns all the immediate child container views into one type (either up or down).

What we need here is a custom alignment and the OP’s custom alignment is perfect. So let’s use it and replace all the text baselines with `myAlignment`s.

e.g.

```
HStack(alignment: .myAlignment) { //CirclesView (solid gray)
```

We get the same as before with all centre alignments because `myAlignment` defaults to `.center`. The black dashed down container still doesn’t know how to choose between all the `myAlignments` of its children without some help from the developer. We need to explicitly tell the `DownContainerView`/`VStack` how to calculate the value of `myAlignment` which is half a circle hight from its top and then give it that alignment guide. Similarly the `UpContainerView`/`VStack` needs a `.myAlignment` guide half a circle height above its `.bottom`.

```
VStack(alignment: .leading) { //DownContainerView
.
.
.
}
.alignmentGuide(.myAlignment) { d in
    d[.top] + halfCircleHeight
}
```

and

```
VStack(alignment: .leading) { //UpContainerView
.
.
.
}
.alignmentGuide(.myAlignment) { d in
    d[.bottom] - halfCircleHeight
}
```

Now critically the `CirclesView` specifies what alignment it wants with `(alignment: .myAlignment)` and the `Up/DownContainerView` returns where that is with `.alignmentGuide(.myAlignment)`

This is the result:

[image: custom alignment]

Now the eagle eyed amongst you will have noticed that the top row blue, red and yellow circles do not line up exactly, and similarly the bottom red and pink circles do not line up exactly. This is because I have used a constant

```
private let halfCircleHeight = 6.0
```

for my calculations (half the default system font height.) Text has a little bit of white space above and below the line that I have not accounted for, and variations in font size would also misalign things slightly.

This is where preferences would come in. If you have different sized `Circle`s or `.padding` or some other effect you may need to get the `Up/DownContainerViews` to interrogate their child view preferences to get the correct value to use in their alignment guide calculation. If this was wanted the child would use an `anchorPreference` to record its centre and the `Up/DownContainerView` would choose between all the child view preferences and use the appropriate one in its alignment guide calculation. (This is left as an exercise for the reader.) By the way, an anchorPreference is simply a preference that carries with it information about the coordinate system it is defined. The child can set the value in its coordinate system (its own centre) and the parent can read the value in its coordinate system (where that is in the parent view).

In summary there are no conflicts with alignment guides because there is only one value and therefore nothing to conflict with. Hopefully this explains why the OPs two green circles `.myAlignment` which have defaulted to `.center` aligns with the `VStack` (in the `DownContainerView`) `.myAlignment` which has also defaulted to `.center`.